# Scroll Bar position in Ultragrid

Tags: c#, .net, scroll, grid, infragistics

Currently, I am using an Infragistics `UltraGrid` in Windows Forms application. I have columns generated in the grid dynamically. I have nearly 20 columns inside the grid and therefore also has a horizontal scroll bar in the grid. I have all my columns in disabled state (read-only) except the last one.

But now the problem is, whenever I open the application, the grid is loaded with the scroll bar on the extreme right side to show the active column. But I want the scroll bar to be on left side so always the first column of the grid is visible. I could not find any scroll bar position related properties in the grid. I also tried seeing some scrollbar related events but nothing worked. Do anyone have any idea what can be done. I have also posted this question in [Infragistics forum](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/86429/431057.aspx#431057) and waiting for answer. Could you please help me to get around this problem?

I am also unable to understand what code sample is to be posted. I dont think of any helpful code extract for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I try to reproduce your issue using our latest available version - 13.2.20132.2010, but without success. The grid show the first column. Could you please tell me what is your current version. Are you able to upload small sample that reproduce this issue. I`ll be glad to research it for you.
Are you using Save/Load layout methods of your grid, because this is one possible reason for this behavior or maybe somewhere into your code you call Scroll methods.
Let me know if you have any questions.